# Doctrine2 Limit the rows to sum in a query

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a query that return a sum, but I want to limit the number of rows to query, but is not working.

This is my query:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('result')
        ->select('SUM(result.generalPoints) AS generalPoints, SUM(result.coefficient) AS coefficient')
        ->join('result.inscription', 'inscription', Join::WITH, 'inscription.user = :user')
        ->join('inscription.race', 'race')
        ->join('inscription.category', 'category', Join::WITH, 'category.generalRanking = true')
        ->join('race.event', 'event')
        ->join('event.competitionSeason', 'competitionSeason', Join::WITH, 'competitionSeason = :competitionSeason')
        ->orderBy('generalPoints', 'DESC')
        ->addOrderBy('coefficient', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('competitionSeason', $competitionSeason)
        ->setParameter('user', $user);

    if (isset($limit)) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Some idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `sum` is an aggregation function its result is one row, the limit statement is applied afterwards. You need create subquery producing multiple rows with `generalPoints` and `coefficient`, limit number of rows in this subquery and use the aggregation function in the wrapping query.